# How to describe an interface that should accept different interfaces of a certain structure?

Tags: typescript

I need function to receive a parameter with interfaces with a certain structure: it should be a string hash or string hash and an attribute string hash type like these objects:

```
{
  anotherHash: {
    a: 'a',
    b: 'b'
    ...
  }
  c: 'c',
  d: 'd',
  ...
}

{
  anotherHash: {
    a: 'a',
    b: 'b',
    ...
  }
}

{
  c: 'c',
  d: 'd',
  ...
}
```

I try to describe primitives but without success

```
interface IStringHash {
    [key: string]: string;
}

interface IModule {
    anotherHash?: IStringHash;
    [key: string]: string | IStringHash | undefined;
}

const myFunc(css: IModule): any => {...}
```

if I try to pass into function an object with real interface like

```
interface IModule1 {
    anotherHash: {
      ala: string
    };
    foo: string,
    bar: string
}
```

which describe the object

```
const myObject: IModule1 = {
  anotherHash: {
    ala: 'boom'
  }
  foo: 'foo',
  bar: 'bar'
}
```

it throws error about difference in types:

`Argument of type 'IModule1' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IModule'.
  Index signature is missing in type 'IModule1'.
const myObject: IModule1`

Here is should be meta description but I don't know how to express it in typescript

here is the [play](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20IStringHash%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IModule%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20anotherHash%3F%3A%20IStringHash%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%20%7C%20IStringHash%20%7C%20undefined%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20MyFunction%20%3D%20(obj%3A%20IModule)%3A%20any%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%22Hello%20World!%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IModule1%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20anotherHash%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20ala%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20myObject%3A%20IModule1%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20anotherHash%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20ala%3A%20'boom'%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20foo%3A%20'foo'%2C%0D%0A%20%20bar%3A%20'bar'%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AMyFunction(myObject)%0D%0A)

Comment: What error are you getting, it seems to work (if you have strictNullChecks you need `string | IStringHash |undefined`): https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IStringHash%20%7B%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%3B%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20IModule%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20anotherHash%3F%3A%20IStringHash%3B%0D%0A%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%20%7C%20IStringHash%20%7Cundefined%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20myFunc(css%3A%20IModule)%3A%20any%20%7B%7D%0D%0AmyFunc(%7B%0D%0A%20%20anotherHash%3A%20%7B%20ala%3A%20'boom'%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20foo%3A%20'foo'%2C%0D%0A%20%20bar%3A%20'bar'%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: Argument of type 'IModule1' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IModule'.
  Index signature is missing in type 'IModule1'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IModule` and `IStringHash` both define a `string` indexer. This means that arbitrary strings can be used to access properties and thus random properties can be added. `IModule1` does not access by an arbitrary key, it requires that the properties are exactly those specified.

This is the root of the incompatibility. Since `myFunc` can index with a random `string` it could violate the constraints of `IModule1`. If we pass an object literal directly we don't have the issue as the object literal will be extended to include an index signature:

```
MyFunction({
    anotherHash: {
        ala: 'boom'
    },
    foo: 'foo',
    bar: 'bar'
});
```

We can add index signatures to `IModule1`:

```
interface IModule1 {
    anotherHash: {
        [key: string]: string;
        ala: string
    };
    foo: string,
    bar: string,
    [key: string]: string | IStringHash | undefined;
}

const myObject: IModule1 = {
    anotherHash: {
        ala: 'boom'
    },
    foo: 'foo',
    bar: 'bar'
}

MyFunction(myObject)
```

A more convoluted method that does not require the addition of a string index would be to use mapped types to express the constraint:

```
type IStringHash<K extends string> = {
    [P in K]: string;
}

type IModule<T extends string, TOther extends string> = {
    [P in T]: "anotherHash" extends P ? IStringHash<TOther> : string;
}

const MyFunction = <T extends string, TOther extends string>(obj: IModule<T, TOther>): any => { 
    return "Hello World!"
}

interface IModule1 {
    anotherHash: {
        ala: string
    };
    foo: string,
    bar: string
}

const myObject: IModule1 = {
    anotherHash: {
        ala: 'boom'
    },
    foo: 'foo',
    bar: 'bar'
};

MyFunction(myObject)
```

Comment: Hi Titian!
Could you help to describe in mapped types such type of object ?

`const MyObject = {
   locals: IStringHash;
   use: Function;
   unuse: Function;
   [key]: string; // any count of string keys
}`

Thanks

Comment: @Vadim please post it as a question.. I can't really post full answers in comments. Also I can't write an answer right now maybe someone else wil pick it up :)

Comment: I've created the question [[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53120144/typescript-how-to-describe-in-generics-object-interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53120144/typescript-how-to-describe-in-generics-object-interface)