# How to describe in generics object interface in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have objects like this:

```
{
  classNames: {
    foo: 'foo',
    ....
    bar: 'bar'
  },
  method1: () => {....},
  method2: () => {....},
  stringKey1: 'stringKey1',
  ...
  stringKeyN: 'stringKeyN',
}
```

I need to describe a function parameter for function

```
function func1(myObj) { ... }
```

My description has failed

```
interface IMyObject {
  classNames: [key: string]: string;
  method1: Function;
  method2: Function;
  [key: string]: string | undefined;
}
```

errors:

- Property 'classNames' of type '[any, string]' is not assignable to
  string index type 'string'.
- Property 'method1' of type 'Function' is
  not assignable to string index type 'string'.
- Property 'method2' of
  type 'Function' is not assignable to string index type 'string'.

Comment: what do you want?, it is unclear

Comment: describe such type of objects in typescript

Comment: just create an interface for your object

Comment: Please, try to - I've tryed without succes

Comment: show all your object properties

Comment: Please review the guidelines about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what constitutes a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is caused by attempting to specify the indexed type alongside "exceptions" to that type.

If you look at the below code (which should be what you are after) - if the `Example` interface had the index signature, it would conflict with the other members. For example `method1` doesn't conform to this: `[index: string]: string;`

```
interface Example {
    classNames: { [index: string]: string; };
    method1: () => void;
    method2: () => void;
}

interface Example1 {
    [index: string]: string;
}

type ExampleUnion = Example | Example1;

const x: ExampleUnion = {
  classNames: {
    foo: 'foo',
    bar: 'bar'
  },
  method1: () => {},
  method2: () => {},
  stringKey1: 'stringKey1',
  stringKeyN: 'stringKeyN',
}
```

Now this causes you issues on access, because the two interfaces are still in conflict. You *could* solve that with custom type guards, but a different shape would resolve all your problems in one go:

```
interface Example {
    classNames: { [index: string]: string; };
    propertyBag: { [index: string]: string; };
    method1: () => void;
    method2: () => void;
}

const x: Example = {
  classNames: {
    foo: 'foo',
    bar: 'bar'
  },
  method1: () => {},
    method2: () => { },
    propertyBag: {
        stringKey1: 'stringKey1',
        stringKeyN: 'stringKeyN',
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I couldnt move string keys from root of object (stringKey1...stringKeyN) to a key (